# Appsubmit review time Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I've tried googling the question but i can't really find a result. It may be due to the fact that it's just not there ofcourse. However, what I was wondering is: If you submit an app to the Google Play store is there a review-time in which Google reviews the app to approve or deny the app to the store? And if there is; What is the average waiting time?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no review time for Google Play. Any and every app can be published.

Keep in mind though that it can take several hours for your app to go live on the marketplace, and even longer for it to be indexed in search results and added to your developer page.

EDIT: As of 2015, apps are now reviewed by the Google Play Store Team. However, it still takes less than a day for the app to go live, usually between 6-12 hours.

Comment: Another thing to mention although any app automatically is available, Google do, do spot checks and ensure that they are legitimate and if they go against the Google TOS then Google can be pulled

Comment: This answer is no longer true, as of 2015. 
http://techcrunch.com/2015/03/17/app-submissions-on-google-play-now-reviewed-by-staff-will-include-age-based-ratings/

Comment: This answer is no longer true, it does go through an automated process first and is flagged for an additional review if it is marked as a risk